# Matlab - Return only rows of a matrix 'A' that not contain in other matrix 'B'

Tags: matlab

How do I return only the rows of a matrix 'A' that not contain some values
(These values ​​are an array 'B')?

```
  A = {'A1',  5  'P01,P02,P03,P04'; 
        'A2'  7,  'P08,P09';
        'A3'  8,  'P07';
        'A4'  8,  'P10,P11'};

    B = { 'P07'; 'P10'; 'P11'};
```

I need to return only:

```
'A1'
'A2'
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Is it safe to assume that: codes always start with P, always have 2 digits, always are increasing, and never 'skip' numbers? If so and if required you could probably get the best performance by turning `B` into a string and using `strfind` on it.

Comment: Your edit completely changes the question! Sorry, I'm voting -1

Comment: Sorry Luis, I will reedit this question as start and will create a new one.

Comment: @TimeIsNear I think that's a better approach. +1 back

Comment: @Luis, thanks I've create a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024280/matlab-return-only-the-rows-of-a-matrix-a-that-not-contain-some-values-of-ma?noredirect=1#comment31602989_21024280

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To remove rows of `A` which contain at least one of the strings in `B`**

Fancy one-liner with two nested `cellfuns` and `strfind` at its core:

```
A(all(cell2mat(cellfun(@(b) cellfun(@isempty, strfind(A(:,end),b)).',B, 'uni', 0))),1)
```

Perhaps the logical indices computed as intermediate result are of interest:

```
ind = cell2mat(cellfun(@(b) cellfun(@isempty, strfind(A(:,end),b)).',B, 'uni', 0));
A(all(ind),1)
```

Namely, `~ind` tells you which strings of `B` are contained in which rows of `A` . In the example,

```
>> ~ind
ans =
     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     1
```

*How it works*: `strfind` tests if each string of `B` is in `A`, and returns a vector with the corresponding positions. So an empty vector means the string is not present. If that vector is empty for all strings of `B`, that row of `A` should be selected.

Comment: Sorry I want to return the rows that have a variable not exist in B.

Comment: @TimeIsNear I believe the first solution does that. The second is merely an additional feature, note that `all(ind)` would give the indication of which rows you need.

Comment: I tried the first solution, but not returned rows with missing value

Answer (score 2):

Variations on Luis' theme:

```
ind = A( all(cellfun('isempty', ...
    cellfun(@strfind, ...
        repmat(A(:,end), 1,size(B,1)), ...
        repmat(B', size(A,1),1), 'UniformOutput', false)), 2), 1)
```

Somewhat against my own expectations, this is a LOT faster than Luis' solution. I think it is primarily due to the string function vs. anonymous function (`cellfun` is a lot faster with string functions than with anonymous functions). `cell2mat` not being built-in is also a factor.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change the way you store the data in `A` as follows:

```
A = {'A1',  5,  {'P01','P02','P03','P04'}; 
     'A2',  7,  {'P08','P09'};
     'A3',  8,  {'P07'};
     'A4',  8,  {'P10','P11'}};

B = {'P07'; 'P10'; 'P11'};
```

Then you can do:

```
for n = 1:size(A,1)
    ind(n) = ~sum(ismember(B,A{n,3}));
end

A(ind,1)
```

Or if you prefer a one liner then:

```
A(cellfun(@(x)(~sum(ismember(B,x))), A(:,3)),1)
```

Comment: Unless you change the way data is stored as you say, `ismember` doesn't work because it only tests for _exact_ matching. That's why I use `strfind` with another `cellfun`

Comment: @LuisMendo of course not, that's exactly why I said if you change the data.